# how can i convert .net 4 to 3.5 in asp

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I wrote a site with asp.net and visual studio 2010.now i want to upload it on host but my host support
.net 3.5 so i must convert my project to .net3.5
for this

```
right click on project->property page->build
```

then i select .net 3.5 and click on ok.
when i want to run my project it have errors from my gridviews and don't permit to publish my website
what is problem?
how can i solve that?

Answer (score 1):

some of the references for the project will relate to .net 4 so they will need to be removed and re-referenced for the corresponding .net 3.5 version (if they exist)

It is important to remember that there are some features in .net 4 that are not in .net 3.5 so areas of your application may need to change

Comment: ok post some examples of the errors in your question and we can help you fix them